# Warning: include_once(/public/../RequirementsChecker.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public/check.php on line 12

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

So, I've searched the whole internet for this error, yet, i'm the only one who have this error,
when i upload the script to `http://exampe.com/folder`and view `check.php` , i get no errors at all and it runs perfectly
but the customer doesn't want it in a sub-folder , And here comes the problem, when i upload the script to /public and run check.php i get

> Warning: include_once(/srv/users/***/apps/quizyask/public/../RequirementsChecker.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/users/***/apps/example/public/check.php on line 12
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/srv/users/***/apps/example/public/../RequirementsChecker.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/sp/php7.2/lib/php') in /srv/users/***/apps/example/public/check.php on line 12

any help ?

Comment: I'm sorry to burst your bubble of feeling special and unique, but no, you are most certainly _not_ the only person who has ever had a "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: i wouldn't call it special, it is just out of my knowledge to see that the website works only in a folder

Answer (score 0):

Public may be the document root of your server. Try not including /public/ in your file path when including it. This generic warning is extremely common and is often caused by typos or incorrect urls.

If this doesn't solve the problem, please let us know how you're including the file so we can further help!